# memcpy to copy local array of struct into local array of struct

Tags: memcpy

In C language, I want to copy 1 local array of structure into other local array of structure.  Sample code example below.   Which is the correct way to use memcpy() in this case?

```
'#define CAPACITY 5

int main(void)

{

typedef struct Prototype
{
    int value;
} Prototype;

int  i;
Prototype   vProto1[CAPACITY], vProto2[CAPACITY];

for (i=0; i<CAPACITY; i++)
{
    vProto1[i].value = i+1;
}
```

Here I want to copy vProto1 into vProto2.  Is below command correct?

```
memcpy(vProto2, vProto1, sizeof(Prototype) * CAPACITY);
```

OR this is correct?

```
memcpy(&vProto2, &vProto1, sizeof(Prototype) * CAPACITY);
```

Thanks in advance. I am confused whether I should use "&" or not.